# Impact factor Vs Rating of Maths journals

Tags: math-history

I have heard of a Maths journal having $A^*$, $A$, $B$ and $C$ rating, and have also heard of impact factor of $1.3$, $0.6, 0.33$, et-cetera.

Can someone please clarify me on what these two actually signify, and how you can use it to judge know the quality of articles in such journals?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: For instance, see http://www.austms.org.au/Rankings/AustMS_final_ranked.html

Comment: For the second term, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_factor).

Answer (score 2):

The impact factor of a journal is the average number of citations an article published in this journal received during two (or sometimes five) years after publication. This is a measure used mostly by administrative worked to judge the scientific output of a researcher (along with other numerical measures such as well known h-index, please google it if you did not here about it). It is very well known that this number has very little to do with the quality of the papers, you should carefully read [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0278) to see the details and very convincing data.

The rating A*, A, B, and C was developed by Australian Research Council to actually have something, which would be based on expert opinions and not on naked numbers, which as was very convincingly shown, can be easily manipulated. It was done only once due to the required resources, and I am not aware about new attempts to make a more up-to-date rating. More or less this rating reflects the opinion of the mathematical community and generally should be preferred over impact factor.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
To the best of my knowledge, the higher the rating, the more the impact factor for the journals I have seen. A number of experts told me that when they get a paper to read, they first browse the author's name...I think this is not good for the young and growing authors cos in such ways, the younger guys cannot publish in very high quality journals.

Comment: @Chuks please read the text I referenced in the post. You will see that there is very little correlation between impact factor and the rating of a journal.

Answer (score 0):

The impact factor tries to quantify the impact that the journal (i.e., the articles it publishes) have on the subject area relevant to the journal's aims. There are different ways of doing that of course, buy typically the number of citations made to articles is a significant component.

The letter indications of journals are a very rough attempt to grade the journal. This is usually done by having a team of experts in their fields assess the journals, rather than just following on some formula. Of course, this may (and often does) introduce biases. The current approach to these letter grades seems to be that it is largely meant for libraries when deciding on subscriptions. Some universities push (by offering cash bonuses for instance) their staff to publish in highly ranked journals, not always with good outcomes.

Typically one would judge the quality of a journal by one's own expertise, using the various number and letter grades associated to the journal as rough gauges along the way. Largely speaking, C ranked journals are not good to publish in. There are known cases where absolute nonsense was accepted to publication in certain such journals. Publishing in C ranked journals may actually have a negative effect on one's career.

Comment: Thanks.
Now, can a journal with an $A^*$ ratting this year be downgraded to $B$ rating in some years time, and vice-versa? Also some journals do not appear in the rating at all...does it mean that they are not good at all?

Comment: yes, the ranking may change each year. Journals that are not included in the list may be good or not. The reason for exclusion from the list is sometimes a mystery (or an oversight).

Comment: For instance, it is still not clear to me why transactions of the LMS is given an $A^*$ rating while Journal of LMS and the Bulletin is given an $A$ rating...see http://www.austms.org.au/Rankings/AustMS_final_ranked.html. Like you said the rating is biased! Perhaps, b/c of the no of pages the transactions publishes.

Comment: @Chuks that isn't necessarily an example of bias. The bulletin and the journal are very difference from the transactions.

Comment: I think they all publish very high materials...so why are the rating different?

Comment: Just to add: there are very well known cases when absolute nonsense was published in A* journals.

Comment: @artem if you can point to such a publication I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: Thanks Artern for this comment. That's why I started wondering why the rating was given at the first instance b/c it is painful to have your paper rejected in an $A^*$ rating journal for an $A$ or $B$ journal to accept it...whereas not all the articles accepted in an $A^*$ journal are of very high quality.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I changed my mind and removed an explicit example of such paper from Annals.

Comment: @Artem yes, it is subtle. Perhaps I should have said that it is famously the case that some C ranked journals accept papers which are computer generated nonsense. Of course, even the best A* journals may on occasion publish work containing substantial gaps, sometimes unsalvageable ones.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Actually the only journal from this list that accepted SCIgen generated paper is A ranked. It is Applied Mathematics and Computations. Other papers were accepted by proceedings of conferences.

Comment: Advanced in Pure Mathematics is also notorious for accepting at least two nonsense SCIgen papers.

Comment: @IttayWeiss A much better criterion for Adv in Pure Mathematics is that they published papers typed in Word. Never saw a one example of a good math paper typed in this processor.

Comment: Cannot stop commenting )) The first paper in the last issue in this journal is by El Naschie (please google if you never heard this name), who is quite relevant for the asked question. In this paper he makes 71 self-citation ))

Comment: @ Artern, I think you are confusing Advances in Pure Mathematics with Advances in Mathematics. The latter has an $A^*$ rating and so rarely publishes low quality papers (by assumption), whereas the first has the right to publish low quality stuffs since it is not recognised/rated :)

Comment: @Chuks I really do not confuse anything here, but thank you for worrying.

Comment: You gave example that the paper of El Naschie was published in Advances in Mathematics which is $A^*$ rated...instead of Advances in Pure Mathematics  which has no rating.

Comment: @Chuks Dear Chuks, I really do not want to continue this senseless discussion trying to explain to you obvious things. At the same time I do not want to make impression that I agree with your totally unsupported claims. So I suggest for you to stop at this point, reread the discussion, and if you have *important* questions, ask them.